# Text from button to TextArea Javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea

So i have a button which sets the value of a textBox. My problem is that i want this text to be added , not to be set, so i can keep pressing the button while the already written text is not erased.

```
contents: [
        {
            id: 'something',
            elements: [
                {
                    id: 'something2',
                    type: 'textarea', }



                 {   id: 'testbutton',
                    type: 'button',
                    button: 'button',
                    label: 'Button1',

                    onClick: function() {
                    this._.dialog.setValueOf("something","something2","Text was set ");
                    }

                },]
```

Comment: `this._.dialog.setValueOf` try `this._.dialog.addValueOf`

Comment: @Anonymous0day No, it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 onClick: function() {
                var curVal = this._.dialog.getValueOf( "something","something2" ) 
                this._.dialog.setValueOf("something","something2", curVal + "Text was set ");
                }
```

Try this solution, i hope it will help you !

Comment: this works fine... and now that i think of it , it's very logical . Thank you !